# How to use global constants in a Meteor method?

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I have a Meteor method where I want to pass in a Day Of Week value:

```
Meteor.methods({
    'insertShift': function(dow, shiftnum, . . .) {
        check(dow, Number);
        check(shiftnum, Number);
        . . .

        Shifts.insert({
            sh_dow: dow,
            sh_shiftnum: shiftnum,
            . . .
            sh_createdBy: this.userId
        });
    },
    . . .
```

Rather than store a string field such as "Mon" or "Tues" etc. in the MongoDB Document, I want to store an int (where 1 = Monday, 2 = Tuesday, etc.), so the call would be something like:

```
Meteor.call('insertShift', 1, 1, . . .) { . . .
```

...if I were inserting a value for shift 1 on Monday.

I'm not sure of the Meteorific way of doing this, though. Should I add something like this to my both\consts.js file:

```
const int Monday = 1;
const int Tuesday = 2;
const int Wednesday = 3;
const int Thursday = 4;
const int Friday = 5;
const int Saturday = 6;
const int Sunday = 7;
```

...and then call the method like this:

```
Meteor.call('insertShift', Monday, 1, . . .) { . . .
```

? or what/how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend using the same encoding as Date's [getDay](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDay): Sunday = 0, Monday = 1, etc.

Here's an example [model](http://dweldon.silvrback.com/models) for shifts that includes a `dayString` function to do the translation:

```js
var DAYS = []
DAYS[0] = 'Sunday';
DAYS[1] = 'Monday';
DAYS[2] = 'Tuesday';
DAYS[3] = 'Wednesday';
DAYS[4] = 'Thursday';
DAYS[5] = 'Friday';
DAYS[6] = 'Saturday';

// Shift model
Shift = function(doc) {
  _.extend(this, doc);
};

_.extend(Shift.prototype, {
  // returns a string like 'Monday'
  dayString: function() {
    return DAYS[this.dow];
  }
});

// Shifts collection
Shifts = new Mongo.Collection('shifts', {
  transform: function(doc) {
    return new Shift(doc);
  }
});
```

Now, you can do things like this:

```js
var shift = Shifts.findOne();
console.log(shift.dayString());
```